Equations for dual cubic curves
Suppose I have a cubic curve $C$ (over $\mathbb C$) in Weierstrass form $$y^2=x^3+ax+b.$$
I would like to find the degree $6$ equation for protectively dual curve $C^*$. Do you know any place where this is written down? I need this info to produce realistic figures of such dual curves over reals. This is extremely classical, but I can't find any source.
PS. The answer of Will Sawin settles the question, but I still wonder if it's also contained in some (old?) book (preferably with pictures :) ). Though, given the complexity of equation, I am less optimistic now...

This is the discriminant of $x^3 + ax + b - (ux+v)^2$ in the variable $x$ as a function of $u,v$, since the line $y=ux+v$ is tangent to $C$ if and only if the cubic polynomial you get by substituting $ux+v$ in for $y$ has a double root (the double root being the tangency point). Hence it is
$$ 4b u^6-4 a u^5 v - 4 u^3 v^3+ a^2 u^4 + 36 b u^3v- 30 a u^2 v^2 - 27 v^4 - 18 ab u^2+ 24 a^2 uv + 54 b v^2 - 4 a^3 - 27 b^2.$$

Thanks a lot! I wonder whether you used any gadget to produce the equation, or just did it by hands?

@aglearner I used Wolfram Alpha. It might be a better idea to use a different Computer Algebra System. It also wouldn't be so bad to do it by hand.
